# Role of TABLESPACE PostgreSQL data base

Tags: database, postgresql

I am using the postgres 9.0 version.

I have executed this query in my database:-

```
SELECT * FROM pg_tablespace;
```

and the out put is this:

[image: output example]

I know that "pg_default" and "pg_global" are default TABLESPACE  but I want to know:

1. What is the absolute path for these
2. what is the main purpose

Answer (score 1):

Tablespaces are [covered in the PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html). I quote:

> By using tablespaces, an administrator can control the disk layout of
>   a PostgreSQL installation. This is useful in at least two ways. First,
>   if the partition or volume on which the cluster was initialized runs
>   out of space and cannot be extended, a tablespace can be created on a
>   different partition and used until the system can be reconfigured.
>
> Second, tablespaces allow an administrator to use knowledge of the
>   usage pattern of database objects to optimize performance. For
>   example, an index which is very heavily used can be placed on a very
>   fast, highly available disk, such as an expensive solid state device.
>   At the same time a table storing archived data which is rarely used or
>   not performance critical could be stored on a less expensive, slower
>   disk system.

and also:

> The psql program's `\db` meta-command is also useful for listing the
>   existing tablespaces.